# right_aws and RMagick/mini_magick: cant create Image object out of image grabbed from s3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, rmagick, minimagick, right-aws

I am trying to grab an image from amazon s3, do some stuff with Rmagick, and upload the image back to s3. I am attempting to do this with right_aws and RMagick/mini_magick. So far i havent had any luck. Imagemagick seems to be installed correctly by testing it with the command line.

Here is what i am currently trying to do:

grab the image with right_aws and store as a RightAws::Key:

```
s3 = RightAws::S3.new(ID, Secret)
bucket = s3.bucket( 'baneling')
key = RightAws::S3::Key.create(bucket, 'flower.jpg')
```

Then i am trying to convert the key.data into an Image file. **If i try with mini_magick** with this code:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.read(key.data)
```

or

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.read(key.public_link)
#key.public_link is public s3 url to image. i.e. https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.flower.jpg
```

i get this error:

```
MiniMagick::Invalid: MiniMagick::Invalid
from /home/adnan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mini_magick-3.4/lib/mini_magick.rb:164:in `create'
```

**If i try with RMagick:**

```
Magick::Image.from_blob(key.data)
```

or

```
image = Magick::ImageList.new  
urlimage = open(key.public_link, 'rb')
image.from_blob(urlimage.read)
```

i get this error:

```
Magick::ImageMagickError: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/360
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I tried various images including jpg and png. I am using rails 3.2.3, ruby 1.9.3p194, ubuntu 11.04, right_aws 3.0.4, rmagick 2.13.1, mini_magick 3.4.

Comment: Zyren I'm facing the same error will you share me what you did with it    
to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance